# Calling Arrays.sort() making all values zero in the array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to declare a array of size 10001 and then need to sort that array. But when I call the Arrays.sort method , all the elements in the array changes to zero. Why??

```
import java.util.*;
class Candy
{
    static int[] array = new int[10001];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int i, sum=0, count=0;
        while(N != -1)
        {
            //int array[] = new int[10001];
            for(i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                array[i] = sc.nextInt();
                sum = sum + array[i];       
            }
            if(sum%N != 0)
            {
                System.out.println("-1");
            }
            else if(sum%N == 0)
            {
                java.util.Arrays.sort(array);
                int k = sum/N;
                for(i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    while(array[i]>k)
                    {
                        array[i]--;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(count);
            }
            N = sc.nextInt();   
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Are you sure they ALL change to zero?  Or just the first `10001 - N` of them?  Go and have a look towards the END of the array.

Comment: Funny how *your* problem is caused by array of size `10001`, and [duplicate problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054069/arrays-sort-not-working-for-long-array) *(from 2 days ago)* was caused by array of size `100001`. Those are curious numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has `10001` elements (`static int[] array = new int[10001];`), and you only populate the first `N` indices of it. All the remaining indices contain 0 by default, and when you sort the array, those 0s move to the front (assuming you only input positive numbers).

You should create the array after you know N :

```
int N = sc.nextInt();
array = new int[N];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it. :)